# Receive TCP ACKs on application level

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, windows-socket-api

Is there a not-very-occult way for a socket application to peek TCP ACKs somehow, so it can know how much data has arrived to the server without the need for a server to send explicit application-level confirmations?

Comment: Doubtful, since many NICs do TCP ACK offload.